HTML Changes That I Made In Footer Show's In My Blog Posts
In my website footer I made backlinks for some pages and I design "link, visited, hover" using HTML and it works and I make the text color "white" for the Links. but all text in the blog post turn white also.
here is the HTML code that I use


a:link {
  color: White;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  color: White;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: White;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
<footer>
  <a href="https://tasteveryday.com/"><h5>Home</h5></a><a href="https://tasteveryday.com/about-us/"><h5>About Us</h5></a><a href="https://tasteveryday.com/contact/"><h5>Contact</h5></a><a href="https://tasteveryday.com/privacy-policy/"><h5>Privacy Policy</h5></a><a href="https://tasteveryday.com/term-of-use/"><h5>Terms Of Use</h5></a>
</footer>




I can’t see any HTML related to the blog pos content.

I've updated your code to a runnable code snippet.  Can you update this to observably demonstrate the problem you are trying to describe?

It's just because you are referring to the anchor tag globally in CSS rather than specifying the accurate anchor tags to be altered.
This would be the proper code:


footer a:link {
  color: black; /** for viewing **/
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:visited {
  color: white; /** for viewing **/
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: none;
}

footer a:hover {
  color: white; /** for viewing **/
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
<footer>
  <a href="https://tasteveryday.com/">
    <h5>Home</h5>
  </a>
  <a href="https://tasteveryday.com/about-us/">
    <h5>About Us</h5>
  </a>
  <a href="https://tasteveryday.com/contact/">
    <h5>Contact</h5>
  </a>
  <a href="https://tasteveryday.com/privacy-policy/">
    <h5>Privacy Policy</h5>
  </a>
  <a href="https://tasteveryday.com/term-of-use/">
    <h5>Terms Of Use</h5>
  </a>
</footer>



Adding footer before a adds a parent-to-child hierarchy which  properly specifies which anchor tags are meant to have the styles

I appreciate your fast reply. when I put this code in WordPress text Block only the second section that worked but the first one didn't only showing the code. I'm not a programmer I don't understand a lot on coding. also the code that I put in the question I didn't writing by myself I just copy it and made some changes and that seems why I had that problem.

should I write 
@SouhailHajib yea of course! It works here because SO automatically detects those tags..

Yeah it's solve my problem for now and that's why I want to appreciate your time and help :*

Happy learning!
